# Any .Net C# code to send commands to the SATO CL4NX/ SatoGL408e RFID printer to print label

Tags: microservices, barcode-printing

i want to write one .net c# microservice(Asp .net coreweb api) which should talk to the SATO printer using printer Ip and port number.
I have certain criteria that where each field should be printed.
Microservice may be deployed anywhere else and the program inside this need to talk to the printer using printer IP and port.
Microservice Api will be called from outside word, using their web Api calls exposed(POST/GET etc).

Not getting any sample code to establish the requirement